# How to fix a encoding error when converting list to csv format?

Tags: python, list, csv, unicode, encoding

I'm getting the `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'"` when trying to write my unicode lists into a csv file:

```
with open('assignmentTest.csv', 'wb') as finale:
writer = csv.writer(finale) #creates csv file to write final lists into
finalRows = zip(firstName, lastName, phdName, universityName, departmentName) #put all of the lists into another lists so that the outputs are in 'column form' as opposed to rows
for rowToken in finalRows: #puts each element of each list together in the same order
    conver = rowToken
    writer.writerow(conver.encode('utf-8'))
```

Originally (without the .encode('utf-8')) I was getting the error:

```
"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

Anyone know how to fix this so I can write my lists?

Answer (score 1):

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

You can only encode strings (specifically, Unicode strings to byte strings).

`rowToken` isn't a string, it's a list of strings. You have to encode each string inside it individually. For example:

```
encodedCells = [cell.encode('utf-8') for cell in rowToken]
writer.writerow(encodedCells)
```